# How to make java swt dialog dynamic

Tags: java, dialog, swt, jface

I have made a dialog in Java SWT. There is a radio button in it. When the radio button is enabled a table appears. I want the size of the dialog to change when there is no table i.e the dialog should shrink to just the size of radio button by ignoring the table.

Presently the size of the table considers the table even when the table is invisible.

Comment: Please show your code which you already tried.

Comment: What Layout are you using for the dialog? Perhaps you should show us a minimal version of your code.